# If algebraic is for algebra, _ is for calculus

Tags: calculus, terminology

Basically what I'm trying to find out if there's something called a "calculaic expression" or maybe "calculussic expression"?

I mean if there are things called "algebraic expressions" for algebra, surely the same must apply to calculus, right?

EDIT:

I'm asking in terms of "Relational Calculus". "Relational Algebra" has "Relationally Algebraic", what would it be called for "relational calculus"?

Comment: Calculus is part of analysis, for which we have analytic.

Comment: @Lucian check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "calculus" has different meanings. On the one hand it denotes the parts of analysis first met by the student, as well as the adopted way of handling these parts. On the other hand it denotes the set of computational rules valid in any particular branch of mathematics. In this sense we have the "calculus" of propositional logic, or of quantum computing. Your reference "Relational Calculus" points to an environment where one deals with various sorts of relations. The objects of this calculus are then expressions whose variables are, among others, certain relations. Therefore I'd call these expressions *relational expressions*, and leave the word "calculic" or similar out of the picture. Note that we call ${\sin x-3e^x\over x^2+1}$ an *analytic expression*, and not a "calculic expression".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the expression at hand: I would say *differential*, *integral*, or [*integro-differential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integro-differential_equation) according to the (respective) appearance of derivatives, integrals, and both.

**Edit** To address the question as modified: Probably the best modifier is just *calculus* itself; e.g., one writes *calculus identity* just as readily as *algebraic identity*. See [this discussion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:differential_calculus) on Wiktionary.

Comment: I've changed my question a bit